# Open 2 modals on top of eachother breaks my scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Well propably the title isn't that clear, i will try to explain the problem better.

i've got this modal:

```
<div id="modalFinestraErogazione" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog higherWider">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <form:input path="codicePrescrizioneRiferimento" id="codicePrescrizione" type="hidden"/>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onclick="chiudiErogazione()">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Erogazione farmaci</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table" id = "tabellaFarmaciPresccritti">
                    <tr><th>Farmaci prescritti</th><th>Dosaggi (die)</th><th>Durata confezione (Giorni)</th></tr>
                </table>
                <table class="table" id="tabellaErogati" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
                    <tr><th class="col-sm-6">Farmaco</th><th class="col-sm-2">AIC</th><th class="col-sm-2">Targatura</th><th class="col-sm-1">Giorni</th><th class="col-sm-1"></th></tr>
                </table>
                <span class='col-sm-12 label-grande label-primary'>Note erogazione (a cura della farmacia)</span>
                <div class='form-group'><textarea class='form-control' rows='3' id='nota'></textarea></div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <span class="label-grande label-default">Durata complessiva terapia erogata (in giorni):</span>
                    <span class="label-grande label-default" id='durataComplessiva'></span>
                    <button type= "button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="bottoneMessaggioMedico" style="width: auto;">Mostra messaggio del medico</button>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr><th style="white-space:nowrap;">Tipo presidio: </th><td><select id="tipoPresidio" class="form-control"></select></td>
                        <th style="white-space:nowrap;">Tipo erogazione: </th><td><select id="tipoErogazione" class="form-control"></select></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class = "col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class = "col-sm-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="salvaErogazione()">Eroga</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "col-sm-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="chiudiErogazione()">Chiudi</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that at some point i show using:

```
$("#modalFinestraErogazione").modal('show');
```

Everything works fine, i add and delete works from the tables etc, and when the window becomes too long i can sroll it down.

Sometimes when the user does someting wrong i show-up a warning pop-up using this code.

```
function finestraWarning(messaggio)
{
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        type : BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
        title : "Attenzione",
        message : messaggio,
        size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_NORMAL,
        buttons : [ {
            label : 'OK',
            cssClass : 'btn-warning',
            action : function(dialog) {
                dialog.close();
            }
        } ]
    });
}
```

and everything still works fine, but when i close the warning dialog something goes wrong.
Suddenly i can scroll down the modal window anymore, instead when i use the scrollwheel the page in the background moves.

I can't figure out why.
What should i do so that when i close the warning window i can still scroll down the modal window?

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I believe this is a default reaction from the modal "API" so to speak. What ends up happening is that it targets the closest element in the body and focuses on it. In the callback function of the warning modal you should have a line that checks if your other modal is open and if it is focus on an element in it. Check and see if this helps, but I think this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: It's kinda hard to recreate the fiddle with the same conditions, anyway i append several <input type="text"> inside the modal window, but even if i set the focus on them (and it works, the cursor is inside the input) still i can't scroll down the modal windows but only the page behind it. At the moment the only thing that works is to do ",modal('hide')" and then ".modal('show')" to refresh the page. I guess that when it opens the modal adds something that is then removed when the window is being closed.